# Boot Camp Assistant cannot be used

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, external-disk, error

I am running macOS Sierra 10.12.4 Beta (16E144f) off of an external SSD connected to my 13-inch retina MacBook Pro. I am trying to install Windows 10 on it.

When I open up Boot Camp Assistant and press "Continue," I get the following error:

> **Boot Camp Assistant cannot be used.**
>
> The disk is not journaled. You must enable journaling using Disk Utility before using the Boot Camp Assistant.

Can anyone help me solve this rather cryptic problem? I tried searching online to no avail.

Comment: What happened next? Specifically, when you tried to enable journaling with Disk Utility?

Answer (score -2):

Your problem is that your boot disk is not journaled. Go to Disk Utility, press on your boot disk (the parent, not the child partition), and press the information icon in the Toolbar. Look for the "Journaled" option in the list. It probably says "No". That's the problem! You need to enable journaling.

Comment: And how do i do this?